# Tomcat should log WARNING/SEVERE but logs INFO too

Tags: tomcat, logging

My understanding is that the different levels of logging, in order of severity, are: SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST.

In my conf/logging.properties I've set all levels to WARNING, restarted Tomcat, but I still keep getting INFO level message in catalina.out. Any ideas?

I'm copying logging.properties below. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = WARNING
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = WARNING
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = WARNING
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = WARNING
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = WARNING
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = WARNING
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = WARNING
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a log message you see with INFO level?

Comment: 15:47:58,233 INFO  ~ type=info, timestamp=1356709678233, class= _class_, message= _message_

Comment: I've never seen Tomcat emit a log message that contains nothing but "~". Do you have `swallowOutput='true'` set on any of your `<Context>`s?

Comment: No, no swallowOutput='true'. What's it supposed to have instead of the "~"? The "type=info ..." is the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat's `logging.properties` does not affect anything in `catalina.out`: notice that `catalina.out` isn't mentioned at all in `logging.properties`? The file `logs/catalina.out` is created via shell redirection when you use Tomcat's startup scripts to launch Tomcat.

Anything that goes to standard output (from either Tomcat itself or any webapp) [will end up in `catalina.out`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Console).

If you have output going to standard output, then you should fix your webapp so it doesn't do that anymore.

If you configure your `<Context>` with [`swallowOutput=true`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) then Tomcat will redirect standard output for that webapp to whatever log file has been configured for that particular webapp (e.g. `3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler` -- though you should probably have a separate logger for your own application).