# java logger tomcat configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, tomcat7

I'm using the **java built-in logger** and I need a specific configuration for a certain web application. That's why inside the class folder of this app I have the *loggin.properties* file with the following content:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

The problem is that only the logs with level INFO or greater are being written in *catalina.out*. On the other hand, if I change the level to WARNING or SEVERE it seems to work because there are no logs inferior to these levels.

Reading the documentation, I found out there's a general configuration file in *$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties*, so I edited the levels of this file to be FINEST as well, but with the same result. If the log level in the files is inferior to INFO, only INFO, WARNING and SEVERE are logged.

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

I read also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072707/tomcat-should-log-warning-severe-but-logs-info-too?rq=1), but based on it, it shouldn't work either when the log level is set to WARNING or SEVERE.

Is there any other place where this can be overriden somehow by setting INFO as the minimum log level?